# SQL script to copy values between bit columns

Tags: sql

I have 10 columns in a table, and I want to copy values from column A to column E where both  are bit columns. No changes should be made to column A at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use update statement without a where clause to copy content of `ColumnA` to `ColumnB`

```
Update YourTable
set ColumnE = ColumnA;
```

You may see: [Update Statement SQL](http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/update.php)

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE table set columnE = columnA
```

you can provide the WHERE clause also

```
UPDATE table set columnE = columnA Where SomeCondition
```